# VBA runtime error 13 Type Mismatch If statment

Tags: vba, excel

I receive Runtime Error '13': Type Mismatch when I try to run the code. Debug highlights the 'IF' statements, but I can't figure out where the mistake is. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim lastRow As Long
  Workbooks("Template Part_II.xlsx").Worksheets(2).Activate
 lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 For i = 2 To lastRow
     If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "#N/A" And Cells(i, 1).Value <> "00000000-000" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Copy
        Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     End If
 Next I
```

and in fact I'm trying to do this:
I have one Sheet where I have 100 Rows of various IDs and I want to copy this IDs to another sheet without possible non ID strings in this case it can be #N/A or 00000000-0000, also I don't want those non copied cells to appear as blanks in destination range.

Comment: where is the `Next` for your `For` ?

Comment: Forgotted to copy it. But it's in code and it's not working.

Comment: What is the value of `Cells(i, 1).Value` when the error occurs?

Comment: Are you aware that you are pasting everything in the same cell? What are you trying to do?

Comment: When error occurs value of cells is not 000000000-000 nor #N/A it's cell above 000000000-000 and I'm not copying everything in same cell I see it copying as it is supposed to till value is not 000000000-000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your accesses to the cell inside a check which ensures the cell contains no error value (e.g. a cell 'containing' a division by 0) like so

```
 ...
 For i = 2 To lastRow
     If Not IsError(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "#N/A" And Cells(i, 1).Value <> "00000000-000" Then
           Cells(i, 1).Copy
           Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
     End If
 Next i
 ...
```

Note: I tried to insert the condition at the front of the existing `If` but it seems VBA does not use short-circuiting therefore the wrapping

---

**Update due to comment**

You may want to change your code like this

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim targetRow As Long

Workbooks("Template Part_II.xlsx").Worksheets(2).Activate
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
targetRow = 2
For i = 2 To lastRow
   If Not IsError(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
       If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "#N/A" And Cells(i, 1).Value <> "00000000-000" Then
          Cells(i, 1).Copy
          Worksheets(1).Cells(targetRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
          targetRow = targetRow + 1
       End If
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: the lack of short-circuiting in VBA has always baffled me :'(

Comment: yeah and the next try was to just 'continue' the current loop iteration -> not available too :D

Comment: Actually that's doable, but it's a bit ugly: Wrap your  `For ... Next` in a `Do ... While False` and use `Exit For` for skipping to the next iteration.

Comment: lol yeah :) but then you have nested blocks as well; cool trick anyway

Comment: Sorry.. wrong way round: Wrap all your code in the  `For ... Next` in a `Do ... Loop While False` and use `Exit Do` for skipping to the next iteration.

Comment: This didn't work for me all it did was that whole column was filled with first value of a column

Comment: Yeah - that's just your code. You didn't mention anything about the desired behavior but just want to get rid of the error which this does. If you tell us what you want maybe we can help you achieve it

Comment: Okay then I have one Sheet where I have 100 Rows of various IDs and I want to copy this IDs to another sheet without possible non ID strings in this case it can be #N/A or 00000000-0000

Comment: I've tried your updated answer but it shows same error as before :( but thank you so much anyway.and also I tried to delete cells that contained those strings and then copy it as whole but it also didn't work

Comment: Sorry, please try again. I missed the crucial part of the previous answer :/ My fault!